# C# Code Analysis CA1822 Warning - Why?

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I have the method shown below which is generating a CA1822 Code Analysis warning. CA1822 says this:

`"The 'this parameter (or 'Me' in Visual Basic) of 'ImportForm.ProcessFile(StreamReader)' is never used. Mark the member as static (or Shared in Visual Basic) or use 'this/Me' in the method body or at least one property accessor, if appropriate."`

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this warning, since the 'reader' parameter is in fact being used?

```
private void ProcessFile(StreamReader reader)
{
   string[] lines;

   lines = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

   ParseFile.IVAFile(lines);
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It means you use no members of the object.  All the items in the method come from the parameters.

Therefore the method can safely be made static.

Answer (score 24):

"reader" is being used, but you're not using "this" anywhere, so you can make the method static.

The only reason *not* to make it static would be if you want to use polymorphism later - e.g. making it virtual and overriding it elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I have found malicious behavior of this message.

In a Situation like

```
void Print()
{
    Console.Writeline(GetType().Name);
}
```

I get this `CA1822` reported, although `GetType()` is an instance method.
However, I found some Explanation, why `GetType()` is actually not a virtual method, not an instead method, and technicly behaving like a static method.

It's just that the code Analysis does not consider this special behavior.

Comment: Have you tried forcing `this.GetType().Name`? Does that remove the warning?

Answer (score 4):

The warning occurs because you don't use any member variables of that class in that method. E.g.

```
this.m_anyVariable = anyValue;
```

Therefore you can/should mark that method as static.

Comment: Why *should* the method be marked as static? What's the benefit?

Comment: Ahh, because of performance. From MSDN: "After you mark the methods as static, the compiler will emit nonvirtual call sites to these members. Emitting nonvirtual call sites will prevent a check at runtime for each call that makes sure that the current object pointer is non-null. This can achieve a measurable performance gain for performance-sensitive code. In some cases, the failure to access the current object instance represents a correctness issue."

Answer (score 2):

I think it is trying to tell you that this method can be made static.

The only thing this method needs to access is "reader", but nothing from the class instance to which it belongs ("this"). In which case, you can safely make it static.